# Running script with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML web page on a linux machine.
In one JavaScriptfunction I need to run a script (bash/perl/python) on the linux machine, in the same directory the web page is.

The script should get two parameters from JavaScript.
It doesn't need to return anything, just to be run.

I tried the following, no luck:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script.py"
});


$.post("script.py");
```

For testing purposes, I used the following python script:
    import sys

```
file = open("C:\\file.txt", 'w')
file.close
```

The script works fine when run manually.
Using the AJAX above, I'm getting (on the Developer Tools) this:

```
syntax error    script.py:1:1
syntax error    index.html:1:1
```

The url is fine, as it opens the python script when I click it on the Developer Tools.

Comment: Just display the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) you'll find

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

In the data: data change to data : `{postName1:myValue1, postName2: myValue2 }`
In your scripts you will pick up these name/value pairs via the POST method.

Comment: Thanks @jeff! Works!